# Array Type returns null in Getmapping request

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, spring-boot

I have a class with a List<> type attribute. When I executes a @GET request using post man List<> type attribute returns null while other attributes return the data.

I am implementing a Springboot rest api using MongoRepository. It has a class called course which has a List type including strings called subjectID. I implemented a simple @GetMapping request to see whether all the data are fetched ok. But while every other attribute is fetched.. subjectID is null

```
@Document(collection = "courses")
public class Course {

private String name;
private String code;
private int passmark;

private List<String> subjectlist;



public Course() {}

public Course(String name, String code, int passmark, List<String> 
subjectlist) {

    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
    this.passmark = passmark;
    this.subjectlist = subjectlist;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public int getPassmark() {
    return passmark;
}
public void setPassmark(int passmark) {
    this.passmark = passmark;
}
public List<String> getSubjectlist() {
    return subjectlist;
}
public void setSubjectlist(List<String> subjectlist) {
    this.subjectlist = subjectlist;
}


}



@RestController
@RequestMapping("/course")
public class CourseController {

private CourseRepository courseRepository;
private ArrayList<Course> c;
private Course cs;


public CourseController(CourseRepository courseRepository) {        
    this.courseRepository = courseRepository;
}



@GetMapping("/")
public List<Course> getAll(){
    List<Course> course = courseRepository.findAll();
    return course;
}


}
```

here's what the code should return

```
"subjects": ["sa01","ds01"]
```

but instead it returns

```
"subjectlist": null
```

Comment: Apparently, you're expecting Spring to magically consider that a property named `subjectlist` in your code is the same thing as a property named `subjects` in your MongoDB document. That won't happen. If the property is named `subjects`, then name it `subjects` in your Java code, too.

Comment: Well. that actually worked. It was that simple. I was searching every where else. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/")
public List<Course> getAll(){
    List<Course> course = courseRepository.findAll();
    return course;
}

 List<Course> course = courseRepository.findAll();
```

The  `courseRepository.findAll()`  will return the list of `course` as well. 
So you will get o/p as follows :

```
 {
   name :"x",
   code  :"y", 
   passmark:"z"
   subjectlist:[a,b,c]
}
```

If you want your code should return `"subjects": ["sa01","ds01"]`  then you have to do an extra effort ...